# Не получается импортировать aiogram.filters.command

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.filters.command import Command
```

Ошибка: Cannot find reference 'filters' in '**init**.py'
Как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй

```py
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command
```